# How to copy multiple files at once to different directories using robocopy?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, robocopy

I have several files inside different folders and I'm trying to `copy` them to another different folder.

For example:

```
[source]                              [dest]                      
C:\Users\Downloads\a\a.txt            C:\Users\Downloads\222\a.txt
C:\Users\Downloads\b\b.jpg            C:\Users\Downloads\333\b.jpg
C:\Users\Downloads\xyz\c.exe          C:\Users\Downloads\yyy\c.exe
...
```

How I could create a script to be executed on cmd and using `robocopy` copy all files at once?

My attempt:

```bash
@echo off 
set obj[0].source="C:\Users"
set obj[0].dest="C:\Users\a"
set obj[0].file="x.txt" 

set obj[1].source="C:\Users"
set obj[1].dest="C:\Users\b"
set obj[1].file="y.txt" 
  
FOR /L %%i IN (0 1) DO  (   
  call echo source =  %%obj[%%i].source%%
  call echo dest =  %%obj[%%i].dest%%

  robocopy %%obj[%%i].source%% %%obj[%%i].dest%% %%obj[%%i].file%%
)
pause
```

Error:

```
2022/12/22 21:03:36 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory C:\Users\%obj[0].source%\
The system cannot find the file specified.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The path is wrong, whats happening?

Comment: And what about using PowerShell with hashtable   and using key/value as Source/Dest pairs?

Comment: @Hackoo appreciate an example, i don't have experience with Ps neither cmd/bash

Comment: The `...` implies you have a list of sources and destinations. I can't see you wanting to maintain that list within your batch file. You have 3 copies in your list, but only 2 in the code listing. The subdirectories `downloads`, `222`, `333` etc are missing from the code listing. Please clarify the problem you are attempting to solve. Where is the data to control the copy operation stored?

Comment: @Magoo this was just an example, knowing how to write the script i can fulfill it with all source/dest data

Comment: Did you try `call robocopy....` (I haven't tried it - just my first notion)

Comment: …and [`for /L %%i in (0,1,1) do …`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)…

Comment: @aschipfl is it possible to run this script directly on cmd without creating any .bat file?

Comment: No, the `%%` syntax with `call` requires a batch file. You could however utilise [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and use the `for` meta-variable `%i` instead of `%%i`…

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell you can do like this :

---

```PS
$Paths=@{
"C:\Users\Downloads\a\a.txt"="C:\Users\Downloads\222\a.txt"
"C:\Users\Downloads\b\b.jpg"="C:\Users\Downloads\333\b.jpg"
"C:\Users\Downloads\xyz\c.exe"="C:\Users\Downloads\yyy\c.exe"
}

$Paths.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {write-host Robocopy $_.Key $_.Value}
```

---

And the result is like this one :

```
Robocopy C:\Users\Downloads\xyz\c.exe C:\Users\Downloads\yyy\c.exe
Robocopy C:\Users\Downloads\a\a.txt C:\Users\Downloads\222\a.txt
Robocopy C:\Users\Downloads\b\b.jpg C:\Users\Downloads\333\b.jpg
```

---

Further reading : [Read all items in a PowerShell hash table with a loop](https://4sysops.com/archives/read-all-items-in-a-powershell-hash-table-with-a-loop/)

---

***EDIT : Tested with xcopy***

```
$Paths=@{
"E:\Batch\SpeedTest\Shortcut-PS.bat"="E:\temp\a\"
"E:\Batch\SpeedTest\SpeedTest_Hackoo_Ookla.bat"="E:\temp\b\"
"E:\Batch\SpeedTest\OLD_SpeedResult.txt"="E:\temp\c\"
}

$Paths.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {xcopy /D $_.Key $_.Value}
```

---

***Results :***

```
E:\Batch\SpeedTest\SpeedTest_Hackoo_Ookla.bat
1 fichier(s) copi‚(s)
E:\Batch\SpeedTest\OLD_SpeedResult.txt
1 fichier(s) copi‚(s)
E:\Batch\SpeedTest\Shortcut-PS.bat
1 fichier(s) copi‚(s)
```

Comment: Here it didnt copied the files, just printed the message in the console.

Comment: @Daniela Yep, it's just for testing the output commands and, if everything is ok, just remove `write-host` before the command `Robocopy`

Comment: Well, [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) expects source and destination directory, then an optional file name/pattern…

Comment: Now its appending a "\" to the end of the text

Comment: see: https://i.imgur.com/pYulAcU.png

Comment: @Daniela Check my last edit with xcopy

Comment: Why xcopy? whats wrong with the previous script? also, isn't possible to copy all files at once instead calling the command multiple times?